# Signing REST API Calls: comon MAC algorithm for Java, php, Ruby

Tags: java, security, rest, cryptography, playframework-2.0

I want to sign the calls to my REST API with a message authentication code(MAC), which algorithm is easily and comfortable to use in Java, php, Ruby and C#?

The longer Story:
My application(Play Framework 2.0) provides a very simple REST API, just a couple services that will be accessible by a limited and known* group of clients. Security is important here, also is ease of use for the clients.

(* known means they have to register with the application first, this is where they get there secret for the MAC, I have no Idea who they are and what technologies they use.)

I want to implement the following approach:

- Use SSL
- Sign the REST messages with a MAC

I implemented a test case where I used my password encrypter([Similar to the example code here](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/05/secure-password-storage-donts-dos-and.html)) with PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1 for the signing. It took me some time to get the signing working, especially because I want to send the signature as an URL parameter and had to encode it two times to get it in the correct format.

The generated signature is a byte[] which I convert to a UTF-8 encoded String with org.apache.commons.codec.binary.StringUtils and then encode it again with java.net.URLEncoder to get a correct URL parameter. The solution works, but feels kind of stupid and overly complicated.

This experience brought me to this question, I want to make it easily and comfortable for my clients to use the service, but also very secure. So, what crypto algorithm do I choose for my signature? What is easy to implement for the most common web plattforms like Java, php, Ruby, C# and at least somehow usable in less common languages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`byte[]` converted to a hexString is probably the easiest format to use for the signatures - hex characters [0-9a-f] don't need special encoding.  Apache Commons codec provides conversion methods under the `Hex` class.

HMAC-SHA256 is the gold standard of HMAC algorithms, and should be present on any platform worth using.